# Pull just the first 4 documents in mongodb using moongose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

i'm using this code to pull my documents in my database and send to my views:

```
Model.find().sort('date').exec(function(error, results) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        res.render('index', {
            data: results,
        });
    }
});
```

And in the client i am doing a loop:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { %>
  data[i].....
  etc..
<% } %>
```

The problem is: i have 200 documents in my database, and i want show just the first 4 documents.. using like this, will slow the DOM load, so i was wondering, can i ask for mongoose pull only the first 4??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`limit(4)`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) to your query chain:

```
Model.find().sort('date').limit(4).exec(function(error, results) { ...
```